# How to add this line to environment variables for OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, plist, exec, environment-variables

So an executable file wasn't working, and I found this post (http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=126972):

> I have added this line to the environment variables:
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/" LFLAGS="$LFLAGS -arch i386 -I/usr/local/lib"
>     ./configure --disable-shared .... --cc=gcc-4.0 --enable-cross-compile --arch=i386 --target-os=darwin*
> ```
>
> and added **--disable-yasm** to the ./configure and it got compiled perfectly."

Knowing nothing of environment variables, I googled and set up a Plist file, but now I am confused.  I am supposed to add rows of key/value pairs?  would the keys be "CFlags", "LFlags", and then what?  What about the export?  Maybe I am missing the mark all together.  I am very inexperienced.  Step by step instructions would be very nice.

Help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the code you quoted, run this line in terminal:

```
$export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/" LFLAGS="$LFLAGS -arch i386 -I/usr/local/lib"
```

"export" is used to tell all the sub processes those shell spawns about the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, i.e. in this example, CFLAGS and LFLAGS.

However, if you don't "export", then the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES you set will only be available for the command follows it:

```
$CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/" LFLAGS="$LFLAGS -arch i386 -I/usr/local/lib" some-command
$some-command
```

the first "some-cammand" know about CFLAGS and LFLAGS but the second does not.

BTW: the "$" symbol indicates a separated shell command.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, that post is telling you to run these two lines of code in your terminal after downloading the source to the program in question:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/" LFLAGS="$LFLAGS -arch i386 -I/usr/local/lib"

./configure --disable-shared --cc=gcc-4.0 --enable-cross-compile --arch=i386 --target-os=darwin* --disable-yasm
```

When the poster is referring to environment variables, it is likely he is talking about the `$CFLAGS` and `$LFLAGS` variables, which are very commonly used within buildscripts to add flags to the compiler (`gcc` in this case).